# I get "Build failed." error for anything I write on Package Manager Console without any other explanation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX20C.png)Each package is licensed to you by its owner. NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.

Package Manager Console Host Version 6.1.0.106

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> Drop-Database
Build started...
Build failed.
PM> Add-Migration init
Build started...
Build failed.
PM>
PM> Update-Database
Build started...
Build failed.
PM>

Comment: Did you try to build and look into Build Output tab?

Comment: @YegorAndrosov I did and it shows that there are some errors but  there isn't any errors showed up into the Build Output

Comment: Screenshot would be helpful - where you see errors and where not

Comment: @YegorAndrosov here you are

Comment: This is wrong tab called "Error List", go to "View" > "Output" > "Show output from: Build". Error list tab can be sometimes buggy, it is better to look for entries in Output instead

Answer (score 0):

It fails to build when there is an error in your code. Make sure there are no errors in your code before you try to add or update, look through all files that you've worked on since you last tried to add your migration or update the database since the error message will only appear when you have that window open.